# Linux: transfer USB "signal" via Bluetooth

Tags: linux, usb, debian, bluetooth, bridge

What I am trying to accomplish is this:

1. Have some device connected via USB to PC A
2. Send any USB signal from the connected device on A to B via Bluetooth
3. Accept Bluetooth signal on PC B and make it seem as the real USB device

I would like to create a Bluetooth bridge between A and B, so that B "thinks" that the device connected to A is actually connected to B via USB.

Is this possible?

- Both are Linux systems, the USB device is not data storage, it's a USB  printer, and I am not using any other hardware, such as a USB Bluetooth dongle.  I'm only looking for a set of software that can make that bridge - it's just a data flow, so I imagine it should be possible to send it from: USB (PC A) > Bluetooth (PC A) > Bluetooth (PC B) > USB

Comment: If you can share the content of the device (if it's a USB storage device, for example), then yes, it's possible, but you have to activate BT discovery on both PCs first, let PC B discover PC A, then access the content of the USB through Windows Explorer. If the USB device is anything other than that, I don't see how, unless it's,say, a USB WiFi dongle, in which case ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) could do the trick: share connection in the dongle properties, and select BT as recipient of the shared connection.

Comment: @Didier both are linux systems as pointed out in the title. Let's say it is not a storage device, but for example a usb printer

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) on how to "transfer USB signals". Either your kernel already has this enabled, or you need to compile your own kernel and enable it.

Usbip works over all kinds of networks, so now you only have to connect A and B via Bluetooth in network mode. Bluetooth offers [PAN](http://bluez.sourceforge.net/contrib/HOWTO-PAN) ("Personal Area Network") for that.